# Function pointer becomes nullptr after constructor

Tags: c++, function, pointers, function-pointers

I have this class that I need to pass in a function pointer in the constructor and call the function later on. Actually, I have 2 pointers. Now, one of the functions stays pointing to the passed function, but the second one becomes a `nullptr` after the constructor finishes running. I've tried debugging and... nothing. It just, becomes null after the constructor. Here's my code:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>

typedef void (TransmitBufferFunction)(void*, std::vector<uint8_t>);
typedef std::vector<uint8_t> (ReceiveBufferFunction)(void*, int);

class Controller {
  public:
    TransmitBufferFunction* transmitBuffer = nullptr;
    ReceiveBufferFunction* receiveBuffer = nullptr;

    Controller(TransmitBufferFunction* sendBuffer, ReceiveBufferFunction* receiveBuffer);
};
```

```cpp
#include "controller.hpp"

Controller::Controller(TransmitBufferFunction* _transmitBuffer, ReceiveBufferFunction* _receiveBuffer) {
  transmitBuffer = _transmitBuffer;
  receiveBuffer = _receiveBuffer;
};
```

And I use it like:

```cpp
#include "controller.hpp"
#include <iostream>

void transmitBuffer(void* _handle, std::vector<uint8_t> buffer) {
  // ...
};

std::vector<uint8_t> receiveBuffer(void* _handle, int size) {
  std::vector<uint8_t> buf;

  // ...

  return buf;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  Controller controller = Controller(&transmitBuffer, &receiveBuffer);

  std::cout << (controller.transmitBuffer != nullptr) << std::endl;
  std::cout << (controller.receiveBuffer != nullptr) << std::endl;

  return 0;
};
```

This outputs:

```
1
0
```

They should both be 1 for true. Anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Please edit your question to contain [MCVE]

Comment: Side note: you don't need a `;` after the function definitions.

Comment: [Continuing the comment from @JohnnyMopp] But it *is* required after a class definition.

Comment: `(TransmitBufferFunction*)transmitBuffer`Why do you cast the functions?

Comment: Yoe do not define a variable of type Controller.

Comment: "the second one becomes a nullptr after the constructor finishes running." Can't verify this statement given only an incomplete unbuildable fragment of a program.

Comment: Ok, somehow, my example does not produce what I get in my project (they both return non-`nullptr`), but I'm also trying it on a different compiler, so I now have no idea whether it's my code or my original compiler.

Comment: Is there something not wrong with your code? `Controller controller = Controller... ) Wow! Use of void* really? Init vars in class and later not in initializer but in constructor body, public data members... A lot of things which can be made a bit more c++ like. And your code can not compiled...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so, wow. Nobody on here would've even found the answer, as I hadn't even posted the problem. My problem was I forgot to copy the pointer in the copy constructor, and I was adding it a vector (which would automatically attempt to copy it). After adding it, worked just fine. Sorry for wasting everyone's time.